# Greedy Nearest Neighbour algorithm for Traveling Salesman Problem in R

Tags: r

I want to write a function that uses the greedy algorithm to solve the traveling salesman problem in R.  For this problem I have been given a set of 12 points and have been asked to start the algorithm at a specific starting point.  I understand the algorithm but am a bit stuck on where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated, questions that are solely about programming are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site and may be closed.  If you have a statistical question, edit your post to emphasize it.  If your question is in fact about statistical programming, see the [list of internet support sites for statistics software](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) that we maintain. You can also request the post to be migrated to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can find quite a lot of resources on the topic online. 
If you needed to use it for large data sets, I would use some packages that have already been developed and tested to start with.
But for such a small task, you could start by having a look at this:
http://www-eio.upc.es/~nasini/Blog/TSP_Notes.pdf
It is a bit long (and it deals with a larger dataset), but it is neat and clear.
I hope this helps.